# Postfix limit queue size

Tags: queue, postfix-mta, mail-queue

Sometimes my RPI drops internet connection and cron jobs starts failing left and right and the queue grows incredibly fast, and once I reconnect it just floods me with email.

I'd like to limit the mail queue to a fixed number, is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can limit the maximal number of recipients and active queue size,

In main.cf please add these config options

```
qmgr_message_active_limit = 40000
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 40000
```

Refer this links for better understanding [active limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#qmgr_message_active_limit), [recipient limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#qmgr_message_recipient_limit)

Comment: This isn't controlling the queue size per se, since Postfix has anin memory queue and an on disk queues...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not really possible.

I'd say a solution would be to either limit the size of the queue (by using the **queue_minfree** parameter) or make the system more robust regarding internet outages (like not sending mails for every error cron produces).